# Keynote PDF export cutting off equations

Tags: macos, keynote

When I export Keynote presentations to .pdf that have equations made using the built in TeX equation feature, the equations appear to be slightly cropped/cut off on the left hand side.

[image]

This is happening on Monterey, MacBook Pro, Keynote 12.

Anyone else experiencing this/ideas to correct?

Comment: Hmm, [iPad isn’t doing that…](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PYQri.jpg) good example showing what you mean

Comment: @bmike Thank you, good to know! I should be able to export via pdf on iPad after making the slides on desktop to get around this (iPad is where I want them anyway). Still, an interesting glitch.

Comment: Yes, I’m all in on iCloud but my hunch is your slide deck, template or choices on layout are causing it. Exporting works great on iOS from my slides and needs

Comment: Add a space to the front…

Comment: Sorry, but can't replicate what you are experiencing with Keynote 12.1 on macOS Monterey 12.4. Exported Keynote presentation with equations in it including what you show above to PDF via Keynote File > Export to > PDF menu using Best and then Good for Image Quality and it worked fine in both cases. Good luck!